# "Implicit conversion from data type nvarchar(max) to varbinary is not allowed" error when storing data using EF6

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-6

I have two model classes - both have a `byte[]` field for storing a PDF file.

In the database the two model classes correspond to two tables - both with a `varbinary(max)` column.

For the one model class, I can easily persist to SQL Server, however for the other class + table I get the error

> Implicit conversion from data type nvarchar(max) to varbinary is not allowed

The two classes and tables are basically similar - except for the names.

I've looked at a lot of answers for for this error, but cannot find any that use EF6. I've created the database tables manually and the classes as well - so no auto-generation involved.

Hope someone can help me past this error.

Thanks in advance

Tried changing column type from `varbinary(max)` to `nvarchar(max)`.

Tried deleting table and creating from scratch

```
//Pdf 
   [Table("SelfBillings")]
public class SelfBilling
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public string OwnerId { set; get; }

    public long BookingId { set; get; }

    public long SelfBillingNumber { set; get; }

    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    public DateTime PeriodStart { set; get; }

    public DateTime PeriodEnd { set; get; }

    public decimal PeriodDays { get; set; }

    public decimal PeriodHours { get; set; }

    public decimal RentalAmount { get; set; }

    public decimal RentalAmountTotal { get; set; }

    public decimal VatAmount { get; set; }

    public decimal TotalAmount { get; set; }

    public decimal TotalAmountInclVat { get; set; }

    //Pdf             
    public byte[] Attachment { set; get; }        
}

//Database table
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SelfBillings]
(
    [Id] [BIGINT] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [OwnerId] [VARBINARY](128) NOT NULL,
    [BookingId] [BIGINT] NOT NULL,
    [SelfBillingNumber] [BIGINT] NOT NULL,
    [Date] [DATETIME2](7) NOT NULL,
    [PeriodStart] [DATETIME2](7) NOT NULL,
    [PeriodEnd] [DATETIME2](7) NOT NULL,
    [PeriodDays] [DECIMAL](10, 2) NOT NULL,
    [PeriodHours] [DECIMAL](10, 2) NOT NULL,
    [RentalAmount] [DECIMAL](10, 2) NOT NULL,
    [RentalAmountTotal] [DECIMAL](10, 2) NOT NULL,
    [VatAmount] [DECIMAL](10, 2) NOT NULL,
    [TotalAmount] [DECIMAL](10, 2) NOT NULL,
    [TotalAmountInclVat] [DECIMAL](10, 2) NOT NULL,
    [Attachment] [VARBINARY](MAX) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO

//Mapping
modelBuilder.Entity<SelfBilling>().ToTable("SelfBillings");
```

I expect to have a record created in table `SelfBillings`.

Comment: post your EF mappings for those tables

Comment: I set up a new database in SQL Server 2017 and used your  "Create Table..." DDL to create the new table it worked so no problems there.  

"The two classes and tables are basically similar - except for the names."   This may be the source of the problem so please post the code for the model classes.

Comment: Original post updated. Cannot find the difference between this "SelfBilling" setup and similar setup I have which is working :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attachment is NVARBINARY(MAX) but I wonder if it is complaining about:

```
[OwnerId] [VARBINARY](128) NOT NULL,
```

Begin mapped to

```
public string OwnerId { set; get; }
```

It's expecting a `byte[]` type, not string for this field likely.

Comment: THANK YOU :-)

That was the issue - don't know how I could miss that. The OwnerId should have been varchar(128). My focus was in the wrong part of the code.

Again - thank you :-)